# how to pass more then two value in url dynamically in react native

Tags: react-native

Add a parameter in URL dynamically in react native in local storage I add the code looks like that:-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('user', (err, result) => 
{ 
        console.log(err, result.id);
        var b = JSON.parse(result);
 }
}
```

and I want to access the user id in URL then how to use them

URL: 'http://8e1c930c.ngrok.io/api/api/polls/questions/+this.props.id+/+this.state.id+/vote/'

when i access ("+this.state.id+") it it show like a string not fetch user id.
so please give me an idea to access the local storage value.

My URL looks like that in ngrok

PATCH /api/api/polls/questions/+this.props.id+/+this.state.id+/vote/ 404 Not Found

Comment: “http://8e1c930c.ngrok.io/api/api/polls/questions/“+this.props.id+“/“+this.state.id+“/vote/“

Comment: or you can use string literals \`http://8e1c930c.ngrok.io/api/api/polls/questions/${this.props.id}/${this.state.id}/vote/\`

Comment: ` ``http://8e1c930c.ngrok.io/api/api/polls/questions/${this.props.id}/${this.state.id}/vote/` `` use grave accent `